# Pushing 80k individual arrays into a multi dimensional array throwing 500 error in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

We are facing the problem while generating the multi-dimensional array.

We are trying to fetch the 80k records from the database and pushing into an array with the following format.

```
while($singleArray = $resultSet->FetchRow())
{
 $multiArray[$singleArray['id']]['field1'] = $singleArray['field1'];
 $multiArray[$singleArray['id']]['field2'] = $singleArray['field2'];
 $multiArray[$singleArray['id']]['field3'] = $singleArray['field3'];
 $multiArray[$singleArray['id']]['field4'] = $singleArray['field4'];
}
```

$multiArray is an multi-dimensional array and $singleArray is a single record from the result set.

We are using while loop to generate the final array ($multiArray). The server is sending 500 error after the execution enters into this loop. We are not getting any error till the result set size is 15k.

To overcome this error, we added the following line at the top of our script.

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');
```

Is this the correct solution? Please let me know.Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need all that in memory at once?

Comment: Why do you need that many entries in PHP at the same time? Usually it is better to just fetch the entries needed and/or aggregate within the database.

Answer (score 1):

Raising the memory limit is the most common solution for handling large amounts of data. You will also probably want to raise the execution time.

```
set_time_limit(amount_of_seconds);

// Or disable the time limit
set_time_limit(0);
```

I do want to know why you would need all this records in an array. We might be able to help in thinking about a quicker and cleaner solution.

*Note:* I don't suggest executing this code in a browser. If you are running a script handling this much rows I suggest using the terminal.